# How can I move files from a full partition to one with more room?

Tags: files, partition, file-copy

How can I move files from a full partition to one with more room?

**Backstory:**

Centos7 partitioned the 1TB hard drive on installation. I didn't realize that the partition mysql installs and runs from only has 50G. It reached maximum capacity and now the mysql service will not start so I can't simply drop or truncate tables. After I get this running I'll be searching online how to keep mysql tables on the large partition. I don't actually know why linux centos needs so many little partitions or what they are for. I don't have an internet browser on the linux machine so I can not copy and paste the output of `df -h`.

The partition mounted on `/` only has 50G while the partition mounted on `/home` has another 800G free.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should copy the contents of `/var/lib/mysql` onto a larger partition, remove the old copy from the space-constrained partition, and create a soft-link to the new location at `/var/lib/mysql` so that the system will find and use the new location instead.

As requested, here are actual commands, but as always please exercise extreme caution before running `rm` commands (i.e., check to make sure that your files have copied correctly -- using, for example, `du -shx .` in both places to check that the total size is approximately the same):

```
mkdir /home/var-lib-mysql
cp -ax /var/lib/mysql/. /home/var-lib-mysql/
rm -rf --one-file-system /var/lib/mysql
ln -sf -T /home/var-lib-mysql/ /var/lib/mysql
```

And, of course, keep in mind that this is a hack and you should refrain from ever creating a user account literally called "var-lib-mysql".

Comment: Thank you for the input. The question is "How?" mv /var/lib/mysql  /home/mysql? How do you create a softlink so that mysql would still run?

Answer (score 0):

- Create 'new partition'.
- Mount 'New partition' to folder 'backup'.
- Copy all contents and permission of '/var/lib/mysql' onto folder
  'backup'.
- Umount folder backup.
- Mount 'ew partition' to '/var/lib/mysql'.